# Using image.variant to resize an image raises a ActiveStorage:: Invariable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing

I'm going through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and am new to rails. The line `image.variant(resize_to_fill: [500, 500, gravity: 'north'])` raises an error, and after looking through [this](https://dev.to/mikerogers0/resize-images-with-active-storage-in-rails-481n) blogpost on resizing images, I am still unsure where I went wrong. Any advice is much apperciated.

Here's the Micropost model:

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :image
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :image,   content_type: { in: %w[image/jpeg image/gif image/png],
                                      message: "must be a valid image format" },
                      size:         { less_than: 5.megabytes,
                                      message:   "should be less than 5MB" }
                                      

  # Returns a resized image for display.
  def display_image
    image.variant(resize_to_fill: [500, 500, gravity: 'north'])
  end
end
```

And here's the view page that uses display_image:

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, size: 50), micropost.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %></span>
  <span class="content">
    <%= micropost.content %>
    <%= image_tag micropost.display_image if micropost.image.attached? %>
  </span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
     <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
      <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete,
                                       data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</li>
```

The two relevant gems I'm using are

```
gem 'image_processing',           '1.9.3'
gem 'mini_magick',                '4.9.5'
```

Comment: Check the `content_type` on your image blob and make sure that `image.variable?` returns `true`. ActiveStorage thinks your blob isn't a supported variant type.